# Why it doesn't maintain reference to the object?

Tags: c#, class, object, methods, reference

I can't figure out why MessageBox show "false" if nuovo.matrice refers to the same object but not maintain the array reassignment done by the method. Why nuovo.matrice == mat is false if they refers to the same object?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication15
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    class Class1
    {
        public ClassType[] matrice;

        public class ClassType
        {
            public string a { get; set; }
            public int b { get; set; }
        }
    }

    Class1.ClassType[] mat;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 test = new Class1();
        Class1.ClassType prova = new Class1.ClassType();
        test.matrice = new Class1.ClassType[1];
        test.matrice[0] = prova;
        mat = test.matrice;
        mat[0].a = "rtuier";
        mat[0].b = 94;
        Modify nuovo = new Modify(mat);
        nuovo.inizia();
        MessageBox.Show((nuovo.matrice == mat).ToString());

    }

    class Modify
    {
        public Class1.ClassType[] matrice;

        public Modify(Class1.ClassType[] mat)
        {
            matrice = mat;
        }

        public void inizia()
        {
            matrice[0].a = "asuidh";
            matrice[0].b = 123;

            Class1.ClassType[] newMatrice = new Class1.ClassType[2];
            Class1.ClassType ins = new Class1.ClassType { a = "pollo", b = 456 };
            newMatrice[0] = matrice[0];
            newMatrice[1] = ins;
            matrice = newMatrice;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you want other people to understand you and be able to read your code, stop naming your classes `lol` and `asd`, especially using lower-case for class names. Use names which make sense and follow common coding guidelines. As for me, I wouldn't try to help just because of this.

Comment: Short answer: here `matrice = newMatrice;` you do not recreate an array linked to `mat` in your `Form1_Load`. You reassign the reference, so that they now point to two different objects.

Comment: I modify class names, sorry.

Comment: How can I avoid reassign the reference but maintain changes that I want to do? @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, they don't ref the same object.. because you cannot alter the `mat` variable in the class. You get a copy of a reference and you're altering the copy. If you want to be able to modify a reference, you should wrap it in a class. Then you'll get a copy of the wrapper reference, but the `Class1` field is unique.

Class wrap example:

```
public class ClassType
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public ClassType[] classType;
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public Class1 WrappedClass1;
}

public class Class2
{
    public Wrapper Wrapped;

    public Class2(Wrapper wrapper)
    {
        Wrapped = wrapper;
    }

    public void ChangeClass1()
    {
        WrappedClass1.WrappedClass1 = new Class1();
    }
}

Class1 class1 = new Class1();

Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();

wrapper.WrappedClass1 = class1;

Class2 class2 = new Class2(wrapper);

class2.ChangeClass1();

MessageBox.Show(wrapper.WrappedClass1 == class2.Wrapped.WrappedClass1); // <--- true
```

Comment: I think the problem is the variable reassignment (last instruction of inizia)

Comment: Yep: `matrice = newMatrice;`

Comment: I don't figure out why the reassignment doesn't affect the original reference if it point to it. Ok, I understand that I reassign the variable, but how can I make that changes affect the original reference

Comment: do u understand what I mean?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean with the explanation in your update. Making change at the copy of the reference will affect the original reference? (I think yes cause I pass a reference type variable through method).

Comment: I want to know how to reassign matrice affecting the original reference.

Comment: You could pass it with `ref`.

Comment: Even if I pass ' mat ' to ' class Modify ' by ref doesn't change the final result ( ' nuovo.matrice != mat ' ) and I want to make them equals after calling ' inizia() ' .

Comment: Because you 'create a copy to the field'

Comment: where I create copy? please explain me completely

Comment: When you assign the parameter to a field. You are creating a copy of the reference. When you reassign it. The original reference isnt modified.